# Can you continue the "begin" clause after an exception in Snowflake scripting?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In my "begin" clause I am using a loop to build a resultset and return that. Ideally I would include an error message in my resultset when I encounter an exception. However, I have not found any concept of a try/catch block in Snowflake scripting or a GOTO statement. I think I'm going to have to switch to a mix of Snowflake scripting and Python, Javascript, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BEGIN [EXCEPTION](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/snowflake-scripting/exception.html) END block could be nested inside LOOP block. Pseudocode:

```
BEGIN
   WHILE ... LOOP
     BEGIN
      ...
     EXCEPTION
         WHEN ... THEN ...
     END;

   END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple example:

```
declare
  result varchar;
  my_exception exception (-20001, 'My custom exception.');
begin
  result := 'Success!';
  
  if (true) then
    raise my_exception;
  end if;
  
  return result;
exception
  when my_exception then
    return sqlerrm;
end;

-- returns "My custom exception."
```

There is no GOTO syntax in Snowflake Scripting